# Al dar 2 click al boton de eliminar ya deja de funcionar, pero doy click en otro boton y vuelve a funcionar 2 veces mas

Tags: php, jquery

Al dar 2 click al boton de eliminar ya deja de funcionar, pero doy click en otro boton y vuelve a funcionar 2 veces mas, o al menos que refresque el navegador para hacerlo funcionar de nuevo.

```
<script>  
  $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.eliminarbt').click(function(e){          

   var ideliminar = $(this).attr("id");     
  $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url:"carrito.php",
      data: {ideliminar:ideliminar},
      success:function(data){                         
          $('.table').html(data);          

      }
  });    

    });        

    $('.btsiguiente').click(function(){

    var total = parseInt($('#total').val());            

        if(total <= 0){
            alert("Carrito Vacio");

        }

        else{
            window.location.href='compra.php';

                }                    

            });          

    });               

</script>
```

Comment: El buton `.eliminarbt` esta dentro de la tabla `.table`?

Comment: has revisado la consola?

Comment: Buenos dia gracias por responder, Si amigo esta dentro de la tabla.

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que se este cacheando... Intenta esto:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Comment: Intente hacer lo que me dijiste, pero  el resultado fue el mismo, muchas gracias.